# Magnitude and phase spectrum of a periodic signal

Tags: frequency-spectrum, continuous-signals, fourier-series, periodic

Let the following T-periodic signal :

[image: Hand-drawn triangular wave with period T]

I found that

$$ x(t) = \frac{A \cdot t}{T} \qquad 0 \le t < T $$

and its Fourier series is :

$$ x(t) = \frac{A}{2} - \frac{A}{\pi} \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\sin(n \omega t)}{n} $$

How do I determine the magnitude and phase spectrum?

Comment: Do you mean _magnitude_ and phase spectrum?

Comment: yes @MBaz exact

Comment: Are you sure about your result for $x(t)$?

Comment: Also, I think you might want to be more clear about exactly what you mean by *"spectrum"*.  I can't tell if you've gotten to the Fourier Transform yet.  If not, there *is* a notion of ***line spectrum*** associated with the Fourier Series.

Comment: can you recheck it please, cuz i tried hard with it thats what i ended up with @Jdip

Comment: ah thanks, can you please the fourier series i written for that signal ? @robertbristow-johnson

Comment: Well, clearly your $x(2T) = 2A$ but in the picture $x(2T) = 0$ so something’s wrong with your expression for $x(t)$. Get that right before going further.

Comment: $x(t) = \frac{A}{T}t$ for $t \in [0, T)$ @Jdip

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For magnitude and phase you need the complex Fourier coefficients:

$$c_n=\frac{1}{T}\int_{0}^Tx(t)e^{-j2\pi nt/T}dt\tag{1}$$

I think your Fourier series is correct, so you can directly determine them from the expression you came up with:

\begin{align*}
x(t) &= \frac{A}{2}-\frac{A}{\pi}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\sin\left(2\pi nt/T\right)}{n} \\
&= \frac{A}{2}-\frac{A}{2\pi}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{e^{j2\pi nt/T}-e^{-j2\pi nt/T}}{jn} \\
&= \frac{A}{2}+\frac{A}{2\pi}\sum_{n=-\infty\\n\neq 0}^{\infty}\frac{je^{j2\pi nt/T}}{n} \\
&= \sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}c_ne^{j2\pi nt/T}\tag{2}
\end{align*}

From $(2)$ we obtain

$$c_n=\begin{cases}\displaystyle\frac{jA}{2\pi n},&n\neq 0\\\displaystyle\frac{A}{2},&n=0\end{cases}$$

The (discrete) magnitude and phase spectra are now given by the magnitude and phase of the complex Fourier coefficients $c_n$.

Comment: so the magnitude spectra is $\frac{A}{2 \pi n}$ or $A/2$, and the phase spectra is obviously $\pi /2$ right?

Comment: @MOHAMEDSALHI: Yes, for positive frequencies (indices $n$) you're right. For $n=0$ the phase is of course not $\pi/2$, and for negative $n$ the magnitude can't be $A/(2\pi n)$ because that's a negative number for $n<0$.

Comment: whats the magnitude is for negative indices $n$ is what? im so confused please

Comment: @MOHAMEDSALHI: I'm quite confident that you can compute the magnitude of $A/(2\pi n)$ for negative $n$, can't you?

Comment: it would be $-A/(2 \pi n)$ ?

Comment: @MOHAMEDSALHI: Well, yes, or simply $A/(2\pi |n|)$, which is valid for both positive and negative values of $n$.

Comment: infinite thanks sorry i made you go through these trivial phases with me, im deeply grateful